# parallax effect | scrollable background image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to implement a scrollable background image (parallax).
Like in a home screen launcher.

An example:
In Evie launcher:
[this video](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/video/upload/v1559369780/Evie)

I've tried using `AnimatedBuilder` mentioned [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html) in the docs like this.

I'm using a `ValueNotifier<double>` as the listener for the animation of the AnimatedBuilder Widget.

The complete code is this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'PageView Scrolling',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{
  ValueNotifier<double> _notifier;
  double _prevnotifier;

  double getOffset(){
    if (_notifier.value == 0 && _prevnotifier != null){
      return _prevnotifier;
    }
    return _notifier.value;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _notifier?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _notifier = ValueNotifier<double>(0);
    _prevnotifier = _notifier.value;

    _notifier.addListener(
       (){
         print('object ${_notifier.value}');
           if (_notifier.value != 0)
             _prevnotifier = _notifier.value;
       }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Size is ${MediaQuery.of(context).size}");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           AnimatedBuilder(
             animation: _notifier,
             builder: (context, _) {
               return Transform.translate(
                 offset: Offset(-getOffset() * 60, 0),
                 child: Image.network(
                   "https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/r2/wallhaven-r276qj.png",
                   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                   fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                 ),
               );
            },
          ),
          NotifyingPageView(
            notifier: _notifier,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NotifyingPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<double> notifier;

  const NotifyingPageView({Key key, this.notifier}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NotifyingPageViewState createState() => _NotifyingPageViewState();
}

class _NotifyingPageViewState extends State<NotifyingPageView> {
  int _previousPage;
  PageController _pageController;

  void _onScroll() {
    // Consider the page changed when the end of the scroll is reached
    // Using onPageChanged callback from PageView causes the page to change when
    // the half of the next card hits the center of the viewport, which is not
    // what I want

    if (_pageController.page.toInt() == _pageController.page) {
      _previousPage = _pageController.page.toInt();
    }
    widget.notifier?.value = _pageController.page - _previousPage;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(
       initialPage: 0,
       viewportFraction: 0.9,
     )..addListener(_onScroll);

     _previousPage = _pageController.initialPage;
     super.initState();
  }

  List<Widget> _pages = List.generate(
    10,
    (index) {
      return Container(
        height: 10,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Text(
            "Card number $index",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.teal,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 25,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      children: _pages,
      controller: _pageController,
    );
  }
}
```

The image can be found [here](https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/r2/wallhaven-r276qj.png)

Now I have two issues:

- The image when using `fit: BoxFit.fitHeight` is not overflowing fully. It's currently like [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/image/upload/v1559382396/Screenshot_2019-06-01-15-14-21-365_com.rithvij.coolapp.debug.png)
- Because the value will become zero when the animation is done it's snapping like this:
  [this video](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/video/upload/v1559370092/Smarter_Launcher_F.mp4)

I tried storing the value just before the `_notifier.value` becomes zero and use it when it returns zero but it resulted in that weird transition that I've shown you in that above video.

What do you suggest can be done to make something like a scrollable wallpaper in flutter?

Something like this

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEMXO.png)

Comment: I Phani, I've answered to the issue you've opened! https://github.com/magicleon94/pagaview_scrolling/issues/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as trivial as I thought it would be.

**TLDR**; [Github](https://github.com/phanirithvij/bg_scroll_flutter) read the comments.

I used a `ValueNotifier<double>` like I mentioned to control the scroll.

Then instead of `Transform.translate` I used an [`OverflowBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html) with its `alignment` property. Which is computed based on the `notifier.value` before rendering.

And to display the image in fullscreen mode:

I used [`AspectRatio`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) with a child [`DecoratedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DecoratedBox-class.html) whose `decoration` is a `BoxDecoration` with its `image` as an `ImageProvider`.

All the code can be found [here](https://github.com/phanirithvij/bg_scroll_flutter) on github. (Read the comments)

And [this issue](https://github.com/magicleon94/pagaview_scrolling/issues/1) on github has slightly detailed info and a less complicated alternate implementation by [Antonello Galipò](https://github.com/magicleon94)

Comment: I know link-only answers are discouraged but the code is huge. Can't say for sure my github account will stay 10 yrs later.

Comment: Great solution, it helps. Actually, I changed it with a horizontal listview.